# Add microdata from schema.org

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to add the microdata from schema.org to my WordPress site, but I do not want to use any plugins. I am trying to hardcode the meta and title for each and every page in the PHP files.

Does any body know how to write the code to add title and meta to each nav element, or each page the site is using? Can I create an array for the number of pages I want to add, and another array for the attributes and tag? Not sure if it makes sense.

Comment: There's no reason to create an array.  WP is a dynamic CMS and your templates should contain the PHP script that dynamically builds each page from data stored in the DB.  Simply edit the appropriate templates to insert the Schema info where needed.

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer. All elements of an WordPress page have their own hooks and filters, which you will need to use in order to get your microdata in place.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My question is, how do I add different meta to each page? because the header is generated by one single file. Does it give you an idea of what I am trying to do?